# Raid5 status is checking means?

Tags: raid5

I noticed the following messages on my system:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
Md3 : active raid5 sda5[0] sdc5[3] sdb5[1]
      3858519040 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [=================>...]  check = 86.0% (1659909504/1929259520) finish=182.1min speed=24645K/sec
```

What does check status mean and why did this happen?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When this happens one of the members in the RAID array has likely gone out of sync with the array, this is the resyncing check that's occurring and it's 86% complete.

When the RAID array is in a healthy state the output will look similar to this:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdb1[1]
      2930266432 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

#### Why did this happen?

I've had these happen from time to time when one of the members gets out of sync. However if they continue to occur then it's likely a good indication that one of the members is starting to fail, and so you should heed the warning and fully diagnose all the members to make sure they're in good health and also identify which HDD (member) is failing and plan to replace it sooner rather than later.

Some distributions may perform a check periodically so you might be getting your array in this state due to these scheduled checks. I believe Debian/Ubuntu may perform a check like this weekly, look for a entry in your system's crontab files or /etc/cron.d directories.

Lastly you can manually trigger a check such as this by echoing the command "check" to the RAID's `sync_action` file under `/dev`.

#### Example

As root:

```
# echo check > /sys/block/md0/sync_action
```

If you need to pause an on going check then you can echo  the command "idle" to stop it.

```
# echo idle > /sys/block/md0/sync_action
```

#### References

- [RealTechTalk](http://realtechtalk.com/mdadmmdcheck_how_to_check_array_integrity_without_rebuilding-1097-articles)
- [mdadm - How to Pause a "CHECK" sync_action?](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/158906-mdadm-how-pause-check-sync_action.html)
- [md man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man4/md.4.html)

Comment: thanks for your explanation slm 

can a lot of write / read operations make this happen?! like under http flood attack which may make a lot of write / read operations?

thanks again

Comment: Sure any additional wear and tear on the RAID could've led to this happening too.

Comment: On Ubuntu (for sure 16.04, probably others too), this is simply a cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/mdadm` that runs `/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray` with cron schedule `57 0 * * 0`.